# Arduino JSON extract using ArduinoJSON Library

Tags: arduino-uno, json

I'm having a problem extracting the Object/Array from this sample json

`[
   {
     "sensor":"gps1",
     "time":1351824120
   },
   {
     "sensor":"gps1",
     "time":1351824120
   }
]`

Would anyone have some pointers or sample code to allow me to extract the 'time' from each of the objects ?

Thanks

Comment: Check the library examples?

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code. Tell us in what way it doesn't work, such as error messages on compile, or unexpected response/behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ArduinoJson Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/assistant/) on [arduinojson.org](https://arduinojson.org/) to create a skeleton.

Here is what it generates in your case:

```
const size_t bufferSize = JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(2) + 2*JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2) + 70;
DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(bufferSize);

const char* json = "[{\"sensor\":\"gps1\",\"time\":1351824120},{\"sensor\":\"gps1\",\"time\":1351824120}]";

JsonArray& root = jsonBuffer.parseArray(json);

const char* root_0_sensor = root[0]["sensor"]; // "gps1"
long root_0_time = root[0]["time"]; // 1351824120

const char* root_1_sensor = root[1]["sensor"]; // "gps1"
long root_1_time = root[1]["time"]; // 1351824120
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  Great library and website to help building the code.